# Transition Matrix (Markov Chain) - 2 Coin Flips

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I'm having some trouble figuring out the Transition Matrix for the following problem:

"Consider a coin flipping game. On each game 2 coins are flipped simultaneously. Admit Xn is the number of tails obtained on the first n games."

We can get 0,1 or 2 tails right? Then the matrix would be:

\begin{matrix}
1/4 & 2/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 1/4
\end{matrix}

But I have a feeling this is incorrect...

Could anyone shed some light on this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Transition between what?  $X_{n}\to X_{n+1}$?  I'm used to transition matrices being used when you have finitely many states, which is obviously not the case here.  Here we have $X_{n+1}=X_n+\Delta$ where $\Delta =  \{0,1,2\}$ with probabilities $\{\frac 14, \frac 12,\frac 14\}$Is that what you wanted?

Comment: There may be an error in the exercise sheet. They ask for a transition Matrix like you defined ( Xn to Xn+1)

Comment: Well, as I say, I have no idea what one means by a transition matrix in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In each game we can have zero tails with probability $1/4$, one tail with probability $1/2$, or two tails with probability $1/4$. It follows then that the transition probabilities for $X_n$ are given by
$$
P_{ij} = \begin{cases}1/4,& i=j\\
1/2,& j=i+1\\
1/4,& j=i+2.
\end{cases}
$$
This is a transient Markov chain as there are no backward transitions, so not much can be said about limiting behavior (other than that $\lim_{X_n}=+\infty$ with probability one.